# Oscilloscope reads correct data from UART but not the receiving microcontroller

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart

I have a rather short question, which is the following...

I am sending data via UART from my RPi to my PSoC. Before connecting to the PSoC, I am reading the signal with my oscilloscope, which among other things shows a correct baud rate and the data is right too.
However, when I connect to the PSoC, it only receives garbage. What could be the reason for this? I am convinced it has something to do with the hardware, since I have a bidirectional voltage level-converter between the RPi and the PSoC.

My setup looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Does the scope show more or less the same trace on both sides of the level converter?

Comment: @SteveFriedl
Yes it does show the same data on both sides.

Comment: What kind of system-on-a-chip chip are you using?

Comment: I have tested my PSoC UART receiver program with other devices such as Arduino where it worked fine, so I also doubt that it has anything to do with the PSoC software.

Comment: @SteveFriedl
I am using PSoC 5LP and RPi Zero W

Comment: I've struggled with the same kinds of things and it's been surprisingly frustrating.  Have you tried using one of the other pins in case the particular A3-B3 level converter might be bad?

Comment: Also: can data go the other way? Transmit from the PSoC to the Pi? Or same issue?

Comment: @SteveFriedl
Yeah it's frustrating. I have been sitting with it for months. And yes, I have tried other pins than A3-B3.

Comment: @SteveFriedl
It is bidirectional, so yes it can go from PSoC to RPi.

Comment: I finally just gave up and used TTL-to-RS232 converters on both ends, which seems like a massive fail.  This shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @SteveFriedl
If you want to take a look, the converter datasheet is here: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/txb0104.pdf

Comment: The data sheet suggests that OE is referenced to VccA, but you've got it with VccB - any chance that helps?  But if you see the proper RS232 data on B3, that seems unlikely.  Have you tried changing bit rates on both sides to see if that makes a difference? How fast are you running the bit clock? This device should easily handle any common serial bit rate.

Comment: @SteveFriedl
I have tried 9600 bauds and 115200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214588/discussion-between-steve-friedl-and-user54952820).

Comment: I'm sure you're past the point of trying to solve this, but on my own similar issue, I changed level converters from the fancy one we were using to a simpler one, and it worked right the first time.

Ref: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07F7W91LC (no affiliate links or anything)

Good luck.

Comment: If you are seeing garbage it usually means the baud rates don't match.  Make sure both baud rates (sender and receiver) both have the same baud rate.

Comment: Measure the actual baudrates from the TxD pin each UART to ensure that they are within a few percent of each other.  *"when I connect to the PSoC, it only receives garbage."* -- Improve your summation with more details, and improve your testing with cases that can provide clues.  E.G. if you send a single NUL character, then what is received, etc?  BTW UART connections using TTL are not intended for lengthy board-to-board links; that's what transceivers are for.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?